# how to parse a csv file using batch script?

Tags: batch-file, csv, for-loop, cmd

I'm pretty new with batch files.
Can someone please help me to write a batch script that will parse a csv file that looks like this:

```
"Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): GET /?password=Katy HTTP/1.1\r\n","Feb 20, 2014 19:34:46.571807000","b5:54:f4:v7:xo:6l"

"Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): GET /?password=Cory HTTP/1.1\r\n","Feb 20, 2014 19:34:51.671167000","b5:54:f4:v7:xo:6l"

"Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): GET /?password=Mike HTTP/1.1\r\n","Feb 20, 2014 19:34:57.145898000","b5:54:f4:v7:xo:6l"
```

and turn it to a another csv file that looks like this:

```
"Katy", "2014-02-20", "19:34:46", "b5:54:f4:v7:xo:6l" 
"Cory", "2014-02-20", "19:34:51", "b5:54:f4:v7:xo:6l" 
"Mike", "2014-02-20", "19:34:57", "b5:54:f4:v7:xo:6l"
```

here is what I wrote:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=6,8,9,10,11* delims=,? " %%a in (file.csv) do (

set pass=%%a
set month=%%b
set day=%%c
set year=%%d
set sec=%%e
set mac=%%f
echo "%%a" %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f

if %month:~1,10%==Jan set month=01
if %month:~1,10%==Feb set month=02
if %month:~1,10%==Mar set month=03
if %month:~1,10%==Apr set month=04
if %month:~1,10%==May set month=05
if %month:~1,10%==Jun set month=06
if %month:~1,10%==Jul set month=07
if %month:~1,10%==Aug set month=08
if %month:~1,10%==Sep set month=09
if %month:~1,10%==Oct set month=10
if %month:~1,10%==Nov set month=11
if %month:~1,10%==Dec set month=12

echo "%pass:~9,4%", "%year%-%month:~1,10%-%day%", "%sec:~,8%", %mac% >> text.csv)
```

Comment: Take a look at the `for` command - specifically using the `/f` switch.  You should post questions here with problems you encounter when trying to solve a problem, not with the problem itself.

Comment: Sorry about that, just added my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
FOR /F "tokens=6,8,9,10,11* delims=,? " %%a in (q21921051.txt) do (
 set pass=%%a
 set month=%%b
 set day=%%c
 set year=%%d
 set sec=%%e
 set mac=%%f
 CALL :CALC
)
)> text.csv
GOTO :EOF
:calc

if %month:~1,10%==Jan set month=01
if %month:~1,10%==Feb set month=02
if %month:~1,10%==Mar set month=03
if %month:~1,10%==Apr set month=04
if %month:~1,10%==May set month=05
if %month:~1,10%==Jun set month=06
if %month:~1,10%==Jul set month=07
if %month:~1,10%==Aug set month=08
if %month:~1,10%==Sep set month=09
if %month:~1,10%==Oct set month=10
if %month:~1,10%==Nov set month=11
if %month:~1,10%==Dec set month=12

echo "%pass:~9,4%", "%year%-%month%-%day%", "%sec:~,8%", %mac%

GOTO :eof
```

I used a file named `q21921051.txt` for my testing.

Nearly there. Your major problem is `delayed expansion` - within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

I've used the second method here

Note also that <kbd>(</kbd>parenthesising the entire routine<kbd>)</kbd> will redirect all of its output using the redirector - `>text.csv` in this case. **The `>` should be `>>` if you wish to append rather than create the file anew.**

I'm not sure what the obsession is with `%month:~1,10%`. Substrings in batch are obtained from `%var:~m,n%` where `,n` is optional; `m` is count-of-chars-from-beginning-of-string, from end if negative. `,n` positive = max length to return; negative = end-position in chars from end; missing=return all after `m`

Hence, since `%month%` will contain `"Feb`, all that is required is `%month:~1%` - but I left your original.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to convert one data into another, like a month name into a month number, is using an [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create the conversion array of month names to month numbers
set m=100
for %%a in (Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec) do (
   set /A m+=1
   set month["%%a]=!m:~1!
)

(for /F "tokens=6,9,10,11,12,14 delims==,. " %%a in (file.csv) do (
   echo "%%a", "%%d-!month[%%b]!-%%c", "%%e", %%f
)) > text.csv
```